# Can boolean properties' accessors be synthesized according to the coding guidelines (ex: isEnabled getter)?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, properties

I've read the [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) for accessor methods and it invites you to write getter methods for instance variables expressed as adjective (ex: `enabled`) as `isEnabled` instead of simply `enabled`.. is there a way to instruct the `@synthesize` keyword to produce such a getter or should you always write the getter method declaration and implementation *by hand* letting the `@synthesize` keyword generate only the setter method? I know they are just guidelines, but I think it is better to adhere to the behavior suggested by the official docs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;
```

This will use `isEnabled` as the name for the getter method.

You will just `@synthesize` it as normal:

```
@synthesize enabled;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I should have seen the getter/setter `@property` attributes in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2).

Comment: !? I think I've misunderstood the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As *@Douwe Maan* mentioned in his answer, ***"you can set the getter/setter method names in the @property declaration and just @synthesize it"*** to let the compiler take care of the getter and setter method definitions.

But, if you want to have your own implementations of *getter* or *setter* or both, you can very well ***"implement the methods in your implementation file and omit the @synthesize line"***.

You can ***"both @synthesize* the property and add your own implementations of getter/setter methods"**, in which case compiler will just use your *getter/setter* method implementations without generating them.